# Is it possible to change the default color of Godot's NavigationMesh3D in the editor?

Tags: godot, color, navmesh, editors, settings

I'm working on a game that uses a lot of high-intensity and pastel color language, and unfortunately, the navigation mesh is doing the same thing! There's a good bit of eye strain there. If I could switch it to something earthier, it would solve a lot of these issues; but I can't seem to find it anywhere in 3D Gizmos in the Editor Settings.

Is there a manner in which I can change the default light blue to something different, and more contrasting with my visual style?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project (menu) -> Project Settings -> General (tab) -> Debug -> Shapes

There you will these categories:

- Navigation
- Avoidance
- Collision
- Paths

Each one with configuration for their corresponding colors.

[image: Navigation color configuration]

Comment: I must be missing something, as none of these colors seem to be adjusting the navigation mesh color

Comment: @MichaelMacha looking at the source code, the colors I see applied seem to come project settings, if it is not these, perhaps it is some hidden setting. I'll try looking deeper with more time.

Comment: I appreciate the effort! All the same, I was anticipating a basic "Navigation Mesh" color, or something like that, in editor settings; apparently it has something to do with vertex colors being used instead of a material. Feels like something that could be made adjustable.